# Custom validation with AngularJS isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm a beginner with AngularJS and for now I'm trying to create a registration form.
I tried to follow the instructions I found on the internet, but it looks like I cannot get my validation triggered. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Here's my JS for the validation:

```
var login = angular.module('login', []);

login.directive('repeatedValue', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.repeatedValue = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                alert("validation");
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and the input field looks like this:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2"
                               placeholder="Repeat password" value="" tabindex="3"  ng-model="login.registerPassword2" repeatedValue/>
```

still, for some reason, even if I start typing into the field, the validation is not triggered and as a result I can still submit the form.

Comment: use the `repeated-value` attribute and let me know

Comment: this is weird, but works :) thanks

Comment: this is not weird. It's like angular works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use right directive name in template (dash-delimited)

```
 <input type="password" ... repeated-value/>
```

See Normalization chapter in docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive